# Why is my screenshot just of the splash screen?

Tags: 14.04, screenshot

Below is all I see when I take a screenshot using the Print Screen key on my desktop. The application that pops up with the option to save/copy the screenshot is just called "Screenshot". I also had this problem on a previous version of Ubuntu, but then only saw a black screen.

I'm using VirtualBox to run this VM, but I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Has anyone else experienced this?

[image: What I see when I try to take a screenshot]

Comment: What tool are you using for a screenshot ? If the command line, what command did you run ?

Comment: Sorry, that was pretty useful information I missed! Updated the question to mention that I use the print screen key.

Comment: What is your host OS and ignoring screen shots does it look normal otherwise?

Comment: The host machine is Windows 8. Everything else works wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug in Virtualbox

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11758

A potential work around is to use VBoxManage, a command line tool, on the HOST

```
VBoxManage controlvm virtual_machine_name screenshotpng Ubuntu.png
```

You could try taking a screenshot from within the guest (gnome screenshot) and transfer the image to the host (shared folders).

If that fails, probably have to wait for a bug fix.